# News by ICD 10 code?

Tags: treatment-options

Is there service online that provides the latest news based on a given ICD 10?

For example if a doctor is treating a patient with E10.9 he could view/search for the latest news on diabetes (drug news, treatments, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by ICD10 code that I am aware of.  But there are for diagnoses, which is obviously what ICD10 codes for.  There are a variety of sites that bring together references by topic.  Most require a $subscription.  Some examples used in the USA include

- UpToDate (usually incorporates recent research into consensus report, but may lag behind new studies)
- Medscape (similarly may lag, look carefully at article date)
- Epocrates
- Dynamed
- Societies like AAFP, AAP etc have by-topic research and guidelines
- Pubmed (the ultimate hub for search by topic, results are scientific journals published)

There are some resources that are integrated into the EMR, depending on the EMR build, which might use ICD10 coding to query their database.

If someone finds something, definitely share it.

Comment: Though I am not a physician and other resources probably provide better updates for standards of care, I would say that setting up PubMed alerts with appropriate keywords is the most efficient way to stay up to date on narrow areas of interest.